# How do I set the same <head> contents on every page in Gatsby using the new Head API?

Tags: html, reactjs, gatsby

Gatsby allows setting `<head>` content via a named export in your page file:

```
// src/pages/index.tsx

export const Head = () => (
  <>
    <title>My Website</title>
  </>
)

const HomePage = () => {
  return <main>Hello!</main>
}

export default HomePage
```

This works, but only for the `/` route of my site. If I create `src/pages/about.tsx`, by default the page title is the full URL, e.g. "https://example.com/about".

**How can I have the same `<head>` contents for every page without having the repeat the `Head` export?**

I know I could extract the `Head` component to a shared location and import/re-export it from every page but that seems really tedious and I could easily forget to do it when I create a new page.

Comment: I'd suggest the following solutions:

(1) Create a template which includes `Head`. Then every page instantiated from the template will incorporate the corresponding `<head>` tags.

(2) Factor it out into a separate file and then import into each page. I know you mentioned this. I agree, it might be tedious, but if you have a limited number of pages then it might be the way to go.